# neo4j: file path on mac (import csv file)

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am new in neo4j. I am using the Neo4j Desktop Version 1.0.18 (1.0.18.81). 
I want to import a csv file into neo4J with Mac which is located in Desktop, but there is something wrong with the path to my file. My code looks as follows:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///Users/nj/Desktop/ontology.csv" AS line    
RETURN count(*);
```

Error message :

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed: Couldn't load the
>   external resource at:
>   file:/Users/nj/Library/Application%20Support/Neo4j%20Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-b793f765-d89b-4120-8dea-b61beab6b4a9/installation-3.3.3/import/Users/nj/Desktop/ontology.csv

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I already commented out the import config line but I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default import is allowed only relative to the `import` directory in your Neo4j home. You should move your CSV there and import from that location.

You can also look at [changing your import directory](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.directories.import) by changing some values in your neo4j.conf file.